# How to set a image in repeat mode at background

Tags: html, css

I want to build a header as follows, and I have svg/png of background asset (zeros and ones). But the size of that asset is equal to approximately 40% of the section width. I want to show that image, so that it appears likes as they are repeating or asset width is equal to 100%.  [image: screenshot]

HTML:

```
<section class="greeting-section">
  <div class="left-side-greeting">
    <h1>"Hello World." from Challengers Club</h1>
    <p>Müxtəlif universitetlərdən, iş yerlərindən ümumiyyətlə tamam fərqli marağlara, malik 
    olan 24 nəfərə müəyyən müddət ərzində proqramlaşdırma biliklərin öyrətmək üçün yaradılmış 
    komandaya qoşulmağa səndə tələs.</p>
    <button id="watch-video"><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>Videonu izlə</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful if you posted your CSS and the actual image somewhere so we could test this.

Comment: Just apply background to this class .greeting-section:
    .greeting-section {
        background: url('image.png') repeat-x bottom left;
    }

Comment: @OleksandrLunov you are great, man, thank you !

Comment: @srvqaqa welcome :)